# How to save a large (60mb+) image to photo library?

Tags: iphone, ios, memory, uiimage, photolibrary

I know the various ways to save a UIImage to the photo library:

- UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum
- ALAssetsLibrary

However, my images are HUGE (60mb+), so bringing them into memory is not possible.  I can download the images by streaming them to disk, and even use imageWithContentsOfFile to take a peek (although that is kind of unnecessary given screen size).

But I want the user to be able to save these images for later.  Is there anyway for me to get these large images into the photo library?  Do I just have to keep them stored locally inside the app sandbox?

Comment: 60MB is incredibly unwieldly for a single image, but have you tried getting any into the photo library yet?

Comment: I think you should think more about why your images are so huge...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that there is no point at storing them at the photo library, since it is designed to be viewed on the device and theres no point at viewing an image so big. If you want to let the user see the image then i suggest you create a preview and save THAT version into the photo library. If you want to let the user transfer them from the device to the computer there is a special folder in your app bundle which will allow those pictures to appear when using itunes and selecting your application. then he can transfer those pictures to his computer. Also could you elaborate on the characteristics of the images? format, dimentions, purpose, etc.

Comment: yeah thinking the folder for showing in iTunes is the best route.   thanks!